# UIButton in UITableView clicks on multiple buttons in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 buttons in UITableview. When i select one button in my UITableView other buttons lower down are also clicked. Why is this clicking one button selecting multiple UIButtons?

I am using storyboard and my code is:

```
- (IBAction)yesBtnAction:(id)sender {
    UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.take5table indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
    UIButton *yesBTN=(UIButton *)[clickedCell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    UIButton *noBTN=(UIButton *)[clickedCell.contentView viewWithTag:111];
    [yesBTN setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.23 green:0.62 blue:0.23 alpha:1.0]];
    [noBTN setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}

- (IBAction)noBtnAction:(id)sender {
    UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.take5table indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
    UIButton *yesBTN=(UIButton *)[clickedCell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    UIButton *noBTN=(UIButton *)[clickedCell.contentView viewWithTag:111];
    [yesBTN setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [noBTN setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show code from where you are calling action methods?

Comment: Check your storyboard to see if you are linking one button to 2 `IBAction`, also makes sure they are not doing the same things

Comment: which code i have to show you @MilanGupta

Comment: can you explain in details @Tj3n

Comment: Are you writing  calling `noBtnAction ` method programmatically from anywhere? Most likely it should be `cellForRowAtIndexpath`.

Comment: Select the button in storyboard and go to Connection inspector, the last tab in the right side bar, see if it have 2 sent event or not

Comment: i am not using programatically @MilanGupta

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/MpVlk)  @Tj3n

Comment: Doesn't seems to have duplicate connection, can u explain more on what you meant by "other buttons lower down are also clicked"? highlight effect happened, or code got executed?

Comment: Check the frames of both buttons if they are not overlapping over each other?

Comment: yes its highlight happen, can u suggest me the sample code@Tj3n

Comment: Are you using a `UITableViewController` or just a `UITableView` inside of a normal `UIViewController`?

Comment: i am using UITableView inside a normal UIViewController @Rikh

Comment: Are you sure the same function is being called twice? Put a break point on the `IBAction`of the button and check if it gets called twice? (Also check the `indexPath.row`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its because of the same function being called. 
Your problem is owing to dequeuing of the cells. Example:
In the first cell, when you click a button, you are changing the `yesBTN` to another color. So when the cell is re-used you are using that same cell with the changed color. What you could try is:

Add the `indexPath.row` of all the buttons clicked to a `NSMutableArray` and in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check if the array contains that particular `indexPath.row`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not properly handling cell reuse.

You need to make sure your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` properly sets the state of each button. This needs to be based on some state you keep track of in your data model. This data model needs to be updated as each button it clicked.

You are attempting to keep the state in the button. That doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I think this code is helpful for u

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     [cell.buttnName1 addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.buttnName2 addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return Cell;
    }
//action for button

        - (void)BtnAction:(id)sender//type 1 button action
        {
        UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
           UIButton *button = sender;

            for (button in clickedCell.ButtonArr)//button create IBOtletcollections
            {
                [button setSelected:([button isEqual:sender])?YES:NO];

                if ([button isSelected]) {

                    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select_toggle"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                    tagType = button.tag; 
    //use local variable Tagtype(NsIntiger)  
                }else{
                    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect_toggle"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }



        }
```